# How angular detect IE Browser？

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Before all, I'm not going to detect IE browser manually and I know detection based on behavior is best practice. Now, we are ready to move on this topic.

I'm recently reading Angular source code and trying to write some polyfill to 1.2.x

I found something interesting in [SnifferProvider](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.x/src/ng/sniffer.js)

We can see in it's source code, it uses a variable **msie** for browser detection. It's not declared in sniffer.js, I also search the project, neither yet. The only way is it's living in Global Object, but as we out put **angular** variable, still not found.

I wonder where angular declared it and how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.x/src/Angular.js#L185

Comment: @Claies I better use global search in source code than searching it with github's search method next time T_T

Answer (score 0):

`var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;`

```js
 var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
 console.log(isIE)
```